# How can I rank group of rows dataframe based on index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

df=

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   1   0   1   1
1   0   0   0   1   1
2   0   0   0   0   0
3   1   1   1   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0
5   1   1   1   1   1
```

I want to create another column "rank" which divides this dataframe every 4 row.

The result I am looking for it

df=

```
    a   b   c   d   e result
0   1   1   0   1   1 0
1   0   0   0   1   1 0
2   0   0   0   0   0 0
3   1   1   1   0   0 0
4   0   0   0   0   0 1
5   1   1   1   1   1 1
.   .   .   .   .   . .
.   .   .   .   .   . .
```

The way I am doing is:

I created a list and splited that list into group of 6

```
seq=[i for i in range(0,len(df))]
nn=[seq[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(seq),4)]
```

then I created a function that maps the value

```
def map(number):
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if number in nn[i]:
            return i
```

and used map.

```
df['rank']=df['index'].map(lambda x: map(x))
```

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do? I am sure there is more efficient way to do it? I would appreciate if someone could help me with this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
df['rank'] = df.reset_index().index // 4
```

Edit to reflect Pault's comment: If you are certain that your original index is consecutive integers starting from 0, you can do without `reset_index()`: `df.index//4`.

Comment: why `reset_index`? `df["rank"] = df.index // 4` works

Comment: @pault Just in case the original index is not consecutive, or not integer, or multiple,....

Comment: Fair enough. I think it's worth editing that point into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.repeat`:

```
result = np.repeat(range(4), 4)[:len(df)]
df['result'] = result

print(df)
   a  b  c  d  e  result
0  1  1  0  1  1       0
1  0  0  0  1  1       0
2  0  0  0  0  0       0
3  1  1  1  0  0       0
4  0  0  0  0  0       1
5  1  1  1  1  1       1
```